# Visual studio 2017 / 2019 add areas missing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-2019, asp.net-mvc-areas

While creating a ASP.NET MVC Core Web app using VS2017 / 2019, came across that 'Add Areas' option is missing from Context menu.

Comment: Pls add your findings here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/home?category=visualstudio

They are the creators of VS2017 and will handle all missing features.

Answer (score 64):

Area is not removed from VS 2017/19 but it is moved in Scaffolding and you can access the area using below steps:

1) Right click on your project and click on Add>New Scaffolded Item

[image]

2) After click choose the MVC area from the Menu:

[image]

3) After choosing give it Name, and after this the Area will be added to your project:

[image]

Hope it will helps.

Comment: The Registration file doesn't get added?!

Answer (score 1):

In my "Visual Studio 2019" I found via right click on project Add -> New Scaffolded Item -> Common -> MVC -> Area is available.

Answer (score 0):

I had a same problem and found that,Visual studio 2017 doesn't support Area

Comment: They have removed the 'Add Area' option from context menu, that's it. But they still support 'Area' feature.

Comment: yes , but user should handles everything menualy , like registering  an Area

Comment: yes everything has to be done manually, like creating creating folders of 'views', 'controller' etc etc which will be hectic task.

Answer (score 0):

I had missing Area on context menu. However, after building the project (2x) the Area was again visible on context menu.