# Visual studio 2019 Add Area missing

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2019, asp.net-mvc-areas

Currently, I created a ASP.NET Core Web app using VS2019, came across that 'Add Areas' option is missing from Context menu.

[image: (right click on project name)]

I tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59783296/7013518) and Add New Scaffolded Item but there is no MVC Area option in below window:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just right click on the project name and add a New Folder named Areas. Be sure that the name is exactly Areas. After that, you can right click on area Folder and add a new area.
Good luck

Answer (score 6):

Apparently this option has not been deleted and has only been moved to the Common section

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To add a new Area, Right Click on application name from solution explorer -> Select Add -> Select New Scaffolded Item -> select MVC Area from middle pane of dialog box -> Enter Name  -> Click Ok.